# With WPF touch why are some properties not directly accessible?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Working with WPF touch, in the code shown below, if I force this line instead of the TryCast line shown in the image, it won't work:

```
prizeWheel.RenderTransform.Angle += e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation
```

Visual Studio reports that 'Angle' is not a member of 'Transform' even though the Debugger Display shows 'Angle' as part of RenderTransform in the drilldown.  I also note that it says 'Angle' is not a member of 'Transform' even though I'm working with 'RenderTransform'.

Why is 'Angle' not accessible as a Double directly off of 'RenderTransform'?  I'm clearly missing a basic concept here.

[image]

Comment: `TryCast`? That's definitely wrong, as it would cause a null reference exception if the cast fails. Always use `CType` unless you are prepared to handle the null.

Comment: I actually just copied that out of the example I was using without thinking and I didn't understand the null issue until you commented on it.

Comment: That's why I mentioned it. A lot of C# programmers also make that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the `RenderTransform` property is `Transform` which is a base class of `RotateTransform` that doesn't have any `Angle` property.

So you *must* cast the property to a `RotateTransform` before you can access the `Angle` property:

```
Dim rt = CType(prizeWheel.RenderTransform, RotateTransform)
If (rt IsNot Nothing) Then
    rt.Angle += 1.0
End If
```

The Visual Studio debugger knows what the actual type of the object in memory is at *runtime* and can therefore show its properties but at *compile-time* you don't know that the RenderTransform property will eventually return a `RotateTransform` at runtime and that's why you need to do the casting.

Comment: All the answers below were very helpful & contributed to my overall understanding.  This one seems to capture all aspects of the issue including the compiletime/runtime issue which is what I didn't understand, as well as advice to use CType.  Thx.  Please confirm in the first sentence above, the phrase "that doesn't have any Angle property" is describing the Transform base class.

Comment: Yes, the Transform base class has no Angle property.

Answer (score 1):

The `RenderTransform` property is a `Transform`, which is an abstract class.  In reality, `RenderTransform` can be a `MatrixTransform`, `RotateTransform`, or a multitude of others.  See the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want access to `Angle`, you need to cast it as a `RotateTransform`.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time, RenderTransform is a Transform object. Meaning you only get the properties exposed by Transform.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform(v=vs.110).aspx

By using `CType(prizeWheel, RotateTransform)` you are telling the compiler "Hey, that thing you think is a Transform is really a RotateTransform."